# Como ler números de um arquivo txt em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, arquivo

Esse é um exemplo de arquivo:

```
2
0.03159527 0.1990048 0.9794891
0.02173799 0.9969404 0.07508247
```

O primeiro número indica quantas linhas são, para cada linha são sempre três números

Tentei fazer algo assim:

```
    Vector3[] Load()
{
    StreamReader entrada = new StreamReader ("gestos_saida.txt");

    int size = entrada.Read ();
    Vector3[] v = new Vector3[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        float x, y, z;
        x = entrada.Read ();
        y = entrada.Read ();
        z = entrada.Read ();
        v[i] = new Vector3 (x, y, z);
    }

    entrada.Close ();
    return v;
}
```

Mas os números lidos não correspondem com o arquivo, como consigo ler esses números sem precisar usar um `ReadLine()` e depois quebrar a *string*?

Comment: Não entendi. O que você pretende fazer?

Comment: Coloca mais partes do código, o que é esse `entrada`?

Comment: Você poderia usar um readline e depois fazer um split por espaço.

Comment: editei e botei o codigo completo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não consegue, tem que ser manual. precisa ler s linhas, quebrar os dados e convertê-los. Considerei que o arquivo sempre estará bem formatado e com dados corretos. Algo assim:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.IO;

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var texto = "2\n0.03159527 0.1990048 0.9794891\n0.02173799 0.9969404 0.07508247";
        using (var reader = new StringReader(texto)) { //só trocar para o arquivo aqui
            int size = int.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                string[] linha = reader.ReadLine().Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                WriteLine($"{linha[0]}, {linha[1]}, {linha[2]}"); //depois troca para o Vector3
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando **ideone**](https://ideone.com/4Q5LEn). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MRoWtr). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/ReadFloats.cs).

Comment: resolveu meu problema, só achei que é resolvido de uma forma muito prolixa, no c++ por exemplo podemos usar o cin sem nenhuma preocupação com tratamento de tipos, o que torna o código muito mais enxuto, imaginei que no c# fosse parecido

Comment: @AndréCarvalho é verdade que C# não é tão bom assim em conversões. Claro que nada impede de criar uma biblioteca que abstraia isso de forma semelhante ao C++. Claro dá trabalho e acho que ninguém fez, o que me dá uma ideia, quem sabe eu faça uma um dia :) É óbvio que a linguagem não ajuda algumas coisas, todo mundo que quiser fazer seu tipo se conformar com esta biblioteca terá que implementar um método de extensão já que não existe o operador de *stream*  no C#.

Answer (score 2):

Entendi sua lógica. Você quer armazenar informações de valores em texto para vetores de três elementos. Apenas não entendi se você quer fazer isso para gerar um único vetor ou quer armazenar múltiplos vetores, mas com certeza ambos casos são possíveis.
Você apenas precisa definir uma lógica para seu texto. Se você for armazenar um número fixo e imutável de vetores de três números, poderá armazenar tudo em uma matriz 3x*n*, onde *n* é o número de vetores-coluna a serem armazenados (no caso, como está especificado como o primeiro número no arquivo de texto). Chamo de "matriz" pelo seu conceito de álgebra linear, mas ela é nada mais que um *array* de vetores, logo será um tipo Vector[*n*], como pelo visto é o que você deseja.

Vamos supor que você queira armazenar tudo em uma matriz. Nesta implementação, o que faríamos é:

1. Ler a primeira linha para definir as dimensões de uma matriz (array de vetores);
2. Ler cada linha de três números divididos por espaços;
3. Dividir cada *string* entre seus espaços;
4. Preencher a matriz com as *strings* obtidas, convertendo-as para *float* ou *double* (dependendo da precisão que você deseja).

Segue abaixo a implementação detalhada:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Programa
{
      public class Program
      {
            Vector3[] Load(string filePath)  // Endereço do arquivo
            {
                Vector3[] v;
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
                {
                    string[] linha;
                    float[] nrs = new float[3];
                    int size = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());  // Leio a primeira linha apenas, com o número de vetores da matriz
                    int i = 0;
                    v = new Vector3[size];

                    while (!sr.EndOfStream && i < size)
                    {
                        linha = sr.ReadLine().Split(' ');  // Divido pelos espaços
                                                           // Veja as outras sobrecargas de Split para mais opções
                        nrs = linha.Select(n => float.Parse(n)).ToArray();  // Uso Linq para selecionar cada elemento e converter para float
                        v[i] = new Vector3 (nrs[0], nrs[1], nrs[2]);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                return v;
            }
      }
}
```

No lugar de float.Parse, use double.Parse para dupla precisão de casas decimais, se desejar. Além disso, recomendo sempre (!!) usar os blocos de *using* como utilizei agora, pois eles garantem que o StreamReader será disposto após seu uso.

*(Obs.: Ainda não testei o algoritmo, estou em Linux no momento. Claro, edito depois se houver algum problema)*